# Missing Boot Options MacOS High Sierra

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, startup, dual-boot

I have previously 3 OS installed on my MBP 2010 13”, MacOS High Sierra, Windows 10 and Linux (Peppermint OS). So I decided to change my linux to ZorinOS and trying to flash it.

However, I think the installer overwrite the MacOS important boot folders/files. Now, every time I turn on the MacBook, it directs me to “GNU GRUB version 2.04”

I can see and try to type in this mode, but I have no idea of what to do with the BASH-like line editing.

I want to get back High Sierra MacOS x back please

Thank you very much in advance for whoever willing to help

Answer (score 0):

That is just the linux version of Mac Boot Options, you should still be able to get to the Mac one by holding option down while booting. If that doesn't work, try command-R, that will get you into recovery mode from there you can use disk utility to clean install or just choose the Mac disk as your start up disk.